# Generating a Cryptographic Key using Fibonacci Sequence in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a cryptographic key using the Fibonacci sequence in Python. I have a specific key (ebe42a225e8593e448d9c5457381aaf7) that I want to use as a starting point. However, my current implementation is not working as expected. Could someone please help me identify the issue in my code and provide guidance on how to achieve this?

```
def generate_key_from_fibonacci(seed_key):
    # Convert the seed key from hexadecimal to an integer
    seed_key_int = int(seed_key, 16)

    # Generate Fibonacci numbers until the key length is reached
    fib_nums = [0, 1]
    while len(fib_nums[-1]) < len(seed_key):
        next_fib = fib_nums[-1] + fib_nums[-2]
        fib_nums.append(next_fib)

    # Truncate or expand the last Fibonacci number to match the key length
    fib_nums[-1] = fib_nums[-1][:len(seed_key)]

    # XOR each Fibonacci number with the seed key
    key = hex(int(seed_key, 16) ^ int(fib_nums[-1], 2))[2:]

    return key

seed_key = 'ebe42a225e8593e448d9c5457381aaf7'
generated_key = generate_key_from_fibonacci(seed_key)
print("Generated Key:", generated_key)
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or suggestions on how to modify my code to generate a cryptographic key using the Fibonacci sequence in Python. Thank you in advance.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: > my current implementation is not working as expected

What is the expectation? what is the current output and what are you looking for?